# Windows Server Automate installation

Tags: windows, powershell

I've run out of ways to try this so I hope you can help.

I am trying to automate the setup of Remote Desktop Services on a Windows Server 2016 machine.

The command I need to run is this:

```
New-RDSessionDeployment -ConnectionBroker $server -WebAccessServer $server -SessionHost $server
```

which needs to be run at startup of the machine but it requires a Domain User (Admin for example) to run the command.  But  everything I have tried doesnt work.

I have tried scheduling jobs and remote PowerShell, but both don't work.  Maybe I just have the wrong technique.

Can anyone shed some light on how this is done??

When the server starts up, it joins the Active Directory Domain and installs the RDS Windows Feature, and then reboots (this is on AWS):

```
Add-WindowsFeature –Name RDS-RD-Server,RDS-Connection-Broker,RDS-Gateway,RDS-Licensing,RSAT-RDS-Tools –IncludeAllSubFeature
New-SSMAssociation -InstanceId $instanceId -Name $documentName
```

On restart, I then need to run the `New-RDSessionDeployment` command above which is where it fails.

A lot of the ideas trying to get this to work have stemmed from https://cloudywindows.io/post/continue-your-automation-to-run-once-after-restarting-a-headless-windows-system/, which works so long as the command doesn't need elevated permissions.

Comment: Hi, what error you got from the command ? It would be useful to state it

Comment: Generally it is Access Denied even though I am giving it the Domain Admin's username and password. I have tried every way I can find  so the question is more about how would you tackle the problem.